# HTML is not working in IE10 but in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have problem with IE10, its not rendering perfectly html in iframe, but works in IE7. in ie10... doesn't seem to have margin applied to paragraph and list.

I use iframe to embed html from another files like

```
<div>
   <iframe src="page1.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">&nbsp;</iframe>
</div>

<div>
   <iframe src="page2.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

here is site link: http://www.doddletech.com/sales_proposal/

Please help me to get ride of this problem

Comment: `G:\sales_proposal_test\index.html` is not your site link.

Comment: sorry, site link is http://www.doddletech.com/sales_proposal/

Comment: The 'link' is the local path to this html-file. We do not have any access to this.

Comment: sorry, i change it to http://www.doddletech.com/sales_proposal/

Comment: It worked for me in IE 10.

Comment: Can you explain in what way its not rendering correctly - we're not mind readers, so assume we know nothing about your html (which we don't)

Comment: @NOX, did it work same like in ff

Comment: @ChrisMoutray you may see in firefox in IE10... it dont seem to have margin applied to paragraph and list

Comment: This may not be relevant to your problem but the frameborder and scrolling attributes are no longer supported for the iframe tag in HTML5.

Comment: They look pretty close - aside from font weight (firefox is more bold), and the width of the content; in IE it appears to be less width - so the `.main` style needs more width to make look the same perhaps?

Comment: what about IE8 and IE9?

Comment: Please confirm that IE10 isn't displaying it in "compatibility mode" or "quirks mode". Either of these mode may be causing rendering issues in IE10.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `<p>` elements for paragraphs, then apply text formatting to these elements instead of adding text directly to `<td>`. If you don't specify any markup and styling to a bunch of text, it will be rendered according to the default stylesheet, which is not the same in all browsers.

As a time saver, you may want to try a [css-reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [css-normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) strategy.

To make a story short:

- **css-reset**: Puts an empty (0-style) stylesheet to override it like
  if it weren't any defined. Then, it's up to you to add every
  styling that should be applied to your page.
- **css-normalize**: Instead of "nullifying" the css, it will do its best to ensure that there is no render differences in default styling, whitout reseting it.

Comment: if you see on second page there is paragraph below the contents, class .contents-text p  not applied on ie

in other pages you see on paragraph there is class .summary p  not applied in ie

Comment: @FrederikL I don't get this. In what way is there a difference in display for `td` in the two browsers, that would not be a problem with `p`?

Comment: @MrLister The OP says that the paragraphs are not rendered correctly in iframes, but there is no actual paragraphs, only table cells that contain a text-node within them. Therefore, it is much easier to debug/maintain a paragraph if there is an appropriate markup to rely on. It is possible to solve this without any markup, but I thought it would be easier for him to solve this first.

Comment: @MrLister i use paragraph everywhere on page only use table(for tabular contents) in 2-3 pages

Comment: @Frederik.L That is nothing to be "solved". Table cells can contain text nodes, just like paragraphs can. There is nothing wrong with the OP's HTML (except from some obsolete attributes here and there), so there is no need whatsoever to change it, certainly not by adding unnecessary markup.

Comment: @MrLister keeping in mind IE box-model's "special behavior", it may be safer to apply margin / padding outside the child, than inside the parent

Comment: @MrLister when applied to the child, wheter the box padding is calculed inside or outside, it won't compromise the design, we can see that as a workaround, or as a way to work with IE